# capybara with rspec visting wrong controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am trying to test my controller by filling some values.i have placed my controller spec file under `spec/feature`. But my visit is not properly working, it is visiting wrong controller.

My controller spec file is

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationsController, :type => :controller do
  render_views
  #the problem is - we need to test criminal record data block from saferent response
  #this guy edwin avila is test input provided by saferent
  describe "GET 'new'" , :type => :request do
    before do
    visit '/TestApplication'
    fill_in 'application[applicants_attributes][0][first_name]', :with => 'Rose'
    click_link_or_button 'sbmt'
    end
        it 'has 200 status code if logged in' do 
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end 
  end
end
```

My Gem file is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'yui-compressor'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'git'
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'passenger'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem "xpath", "~> 2.0.0" 
gem "formtastic"
gem 'simple_form', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git'
gem "rentjuicer"
gem "capybara", :group => [:development, :test]
#gem "capybara", "~> 2.1.0"
gem "daemons"
gem "mongoid", github: "mongoid/mongoid"
#gem "delayed_job_mongoid" #upto rails 3
gem "bson_ext", '~> 1.5'
gem "whenever", :require => false
gem "bitly", "~> 0.8.0"
gem "mogreet"
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'activemodel'
gem 'actionpack','~> 4.0'
gem "carrierwave-mongoid", "~> 0.6.3"
gem 'mongoid-grid_fs', github: 'ahoward/mongoid-grid_fs'
#gem 'client_side_validations'
#gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'
#gem "client_side_validations-mongoid", "~> 4.1.2"
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem "rash", "~> 0.4.0"
gem "activeresource", "~> 4.0.0"
gem 'rb-readline', '~> 0.4.2'
gem 'googlecharts'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'rspec-rails' , "~> 2.0"

gem 'mongoid-rspec' 

gem 'crack'
gem 'simplecov'

#gem 'whoops_rails_logger' upto rails 3
```

when i try to run

```
rspec spec/features/applications_controller_spec.rb
```

i got

```
Failures:

  1) GET 'new' has 200 status code if logged in
     Failure/Error: visit '/TestApplication'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/home_controller.rb:8:in `index'
     # ./spec/features/applications_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.14064 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/applications_controller_spec.rb:12 # GET 'new' has 200 status code if logged in

Randomized with seed 32162
```

my route file

```
mYAPP::Application.routes.draw do
match 'street/:id' => 'home#street', :as => :street, via: [:get,:post]
  match '/pdf' => 'homes#pdf', via: [:get,:post]
  match '/login' => 'homes#login', via: [:get,:post]
  match '/changing_f_gal' =>'homes#changing_f_gal' , via: [:get,:post]
  match '/saferent_test' => 'applications#newnew', via: [:get,:post]
  match '/saferent_result' => 'applications#newcreate' , via: [:get,:post]
  match '/showall' => 'applications#showall', via: [:get,:post]
  match '/visitor/create_visits' => 'visitor#create_visits' , :via => :get
  match '/visitor/init_visitor' => 'visitor#init_visitor' , :via => :get
  match 'TestApplication' => 'applications#create', :via => :get


  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Capybara's visit method won't work for that file path (assuming you're trying to get to the root of your application). Try something like

```
visit root_path
```

I'd recommend checking out the documentation at http://jnicklas.github.com/capybara

Comment: Thanks for reply . but i have defined a route for TestApplication in my route file .

Comment: Is there a specific reason you've defined your route as TestApplication instead of test_application?

Comment: no ! there is no specific reason for that. Actually i am trying to make this thing done by changing routes. and i have also tried your way but it also fails. :(

Comment: Try creating a controller action and view for application#new. It looks like you're trying to visit your create action and enter data when the data should have been entered and submitted by that point. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes !!! you are right i need the exact thing but i already have an action named new and view for that .